# Editing a question that is not awarded as +2 pts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits

In SO. I usually edit posts to make them more readable & clear. Because of being under 2k points, my edits are reviewed before being applied; then if it's submitted, I got +2 points. Recently I've edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168115/saving-data-and-displaying-it-in-a-form-rails-4). However, although being applied with minor changes of my edits, I didn't get my +2.

In addition, I usually check revisions of questions or answers I've edited. If my edits have been applied directly, I become "editor"; but with some minor changes by reviewer, I become "suggester". In both situations, I should appear in revisions of questions or answers I've edited or suggested. However, as it can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24168115/revisions), my edit didn't appear.

[Here's my rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5036872)

I wonder what is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing is wrong.  [Your edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5036872) by a user who decided to improve on your edit and mark it as not helpful.

Comment: It might be interesting but the edit I've made but rejected is approved by another user: I've added both tags, `some corrections...` is my note, lowercasing items, codiyfing column names. That's all I did it.

Comment: @ekremkrc The reviewer himself would need to state why he choose to reject, but my guess is that he felt it was too minor, because the post isn't noticeably better after the edit than it was before the edit.

Comment: it's clear that both edits are very very similar, almost same. I don't want to make disturbance but I'm sure it needs to be investigated.

Comment: @ekremkrc Nothing needs to be investigated.  You posted a minor edit; the reviewer applied it, but didn't mark it as helpful, because it was too minor.  You should make sure that your edits are *substantial* improvements to the posts you are editing.

Comment: FINALLY, I did a _substantial_ edit like others, it should be accepted but another very very similar edit is accepted, my eyes will be on this issue forever.

Comment: @ekremkrc The problem is that so many of your minor edits have been erroneously approved, not that your very minor edits have been erroneously rejected.  Sadly there are too many reviewers out there who incorrectly approve invalid edits, so you haven't been able to learn proper editing behavior up until now.  That its taken this long is very unfortunate.  You should have been informed of this long, long ago.  It's worth noting that, looking through your history, a very significant percentage of your edits have at least one "too minor" vote, you just never collect enough for actual rejection.

Comment: @ekremkrc: the big difference between the 2 edits that I see is that yours made a grammatically correct post incorrect by removing apostrophes from possessives. You were actually making the post worse, not better.

Comment: Are minor edits okay if you're not getting rep for them?

Comment: @Savanna, they are ok as long as you're not bothering 5 reviewers to approve it, i.e., that you have editing privileges.